# Should I consider HTTP response headers' when calculating an ETag?

Tags: rest, http, etag

If I have and HTTP method that returns a `payload` I can calculate an ETag that depends on (and uniquely identifies) this `payload`.

If the same HTTP method is called again later returns a different response header, e.g. `X-Custom-Header: Something Else`, I would like browsers to know that something has changed, even though the `payload` may still be the same.

So my question is, should I consider (some?) HTTP response headers' when calculating an ETag?

Answer (score 0):

If your client is just a browser it will ignore your custom headers so why bother calculating a new etag based on them, page would be reloaded but nothing changes for the browser user, do not do it.

Or may be your client understands the custom headers, like some javascript/ajax code ?